# File permission in batch image writing

Tags: image, matlab

So I am writing a code in matlab which reads an image, crops them after them after fulfilling a condtion. The basic kernel is similar to this

```
destination_folder = 'Cropped Images';
mkdir(destination_folder);
for <initialization, terminating condition>
    ...
    ...
    while <condition>
          ....
          ....
          if <condition>
            .....
            .....
            image_name=image_name+1;
            img_name = [num2str(image_name) '.tif'];
            destination_path = fullfile(destination_folder, image_name);
            file_id = fopen(destination_path, 'w+');
            disp(img_name);
            imwrite(<variable>,destination_path,'TIF');
            fclose(file_id);
            end

     end

 end
```

When I am running this I get the following error

```
Error using imwrite (line 454)
Unable to open file "Cropped Images/." for writing.  You might not have write permission.

Error in Rotacrop (line 65)
            imwrite(NAC,destination_path,'TIF');
```

Also the images are generated to a certain number, but they have random ascii characters as their names

[image]

Not sure whats the deal here

Thanks, 
Fowaz

Answer (score 0):

You got your list of images using `dir`. Beware that even if you don't have any folders in the folder, `dir` will always return the current directory `'.'` and the parent directory `'..'`. Obviously `fopen` can't open the *directory* `'.'`.

You need to remove these results from the `dir` result.

**Remove all folders**

```
files = dir(folder);
files = files(~[files.isdir]);
```

**Remove only `'.'` and `'..'`**

```
files = dir(folder);
files = files(~ismember({files.name}, {'.', '..'}));
```